# serving images from outside the public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

am not a ruby programmer, have to maintain a codebase that i inherited, pardon me if this is a noob question (a quick search on SO didn't reveal much)

user uploads files to rails app, they are stored in /uploads/images instead of /public/assets/

I can get path to them that looks like /uploads/images/image01.png, how do I use that inside an image_tag in a view?

perhaps I should create a controller just to get these files? something like

```
<img src="/images?name=image01.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create custom controller to serve that files and use send_file mentod in it with disposition inline http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file also you may be interested to x_sendfile_header setting to serwe that files with apache/nginx which is faster http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#x-sendfile-headers